# Running ROS, Gazebo and RViz on Macbook

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz

I have recently started learning robotics. Being at uni, I had access to Linux PCs where I could easily run ROS and Gazebo. However, due to the current pandemic and closure of universities, I now have to rely on my MacBook.

Following are the specs of my machine:
Core i7 2.7GHz Quad-Core
16GB RAM
Intel Iris Graphics 655 1536 MB

Is it possible to run ROS and Gazebo simulations on a machine with these specs?
Although it is mentioned on the gazebo website that a dedicated Nvidia graphics card is required, but I have found threads on this forum where ROS and Gazebo run fine on intel graphics. For example:

https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/16824/26934

I also tried running a gazebo simulation using Ubuntu with VirtualBox but got a **Segmentation Core Dumped** error. I did some research and found a thread where it was mentioned that it may be caused by using a non-Nvidia graphics card:

https://answers.ros.org/question/281376/gazebo-is-crashingsegmentation-fault/

Need some guidance on how to run gazebo simulations on MacBook.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have run Gazebo in machines that don't have Nvidia cards for years now, never had any problems with it.

The problem is more likely related to the virtual machine environment, see [here](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/13214/virtual-machine-not-launching-gazebo/) and [here](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/25/run-gazebo-in-virtualbox/) for relevant threads.

In any case, you should consider installing Ubuntu in dual-boot mode. It will help avoid this sort of compatibility issue, and you will make better use of your hardware resources.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Can you please tell me the gazebo and ubuntu version you are using? 
Secondly, the MacBook model I am using has the T2 chip, which doesnt allow installing 3rd party apps. Do you recommend disabling this security feature and dual booting ubuntu?

Comment: I have used various Gazebo versions over the years, currently I'm using Gazebo 9 with ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04. Yes, I do recommend disabling T2 if that's what it takes to install Ubuntu in dual-boot mode.